# Change row height programmatically in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and I need to change the height of the rows based on the height of the ListView. That's because, I would like to show only a fixed number of rows at a time but, given the multiple screens problem, I need to compute the height programmatically.

The problem is, when `getView()` method of my custom adapter returns the view, android arises an exception:

> 07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:471)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:497)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at us.hucare.adapters.ShelfAdapter.getView(ShelfAdapter.java:72)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   07-21 15:17:00.391: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is the first part of the `getView()`

```
if (convertView == null || mDataChanged) {
        mDataChanged = false;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shelf, parent);
        LayoutParams params = convertView.getLayoutParams();
        if (params == null) { 
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mShelfHeight); 
        } else {
            params.height = mShelfHeight;
        }
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

I think the problem should be in that lines because if I execute this code below:

```
if (convertView == null || mDataChanged) {
            mDataChanged = false;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shelf, null);

        }
```

It works normally. (But it shows more rows than I want)

I've found lots of answer on this problem, but no one seems work for me.
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because the line:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shelf, parent);
```

means you want to inflate the layout **and** add that inflated layout to the *parent* `ViewGroup` which will fail as `ListView`(being a child of `AdapterView`) doesn't allow direct child views addition. Instead you probably want:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shelf, parent, false);
```

After that you can set the `LayoutParams` with the desired height(I would recommend that you use the proper `LayoutParams`, `AbsListView.LayoutParams`).